# Tunnelling HTTP over a custom protocol in Clojure/Java

Tags: java, http, clojure

I want to tunnel a HTTP request stream over a custom transport protocol. Are there any Clojure or, as a fallback, Java HTTP clients that'd let me access the underlying request streams or lets me filter the serialised requests and responses?

I know `clj-http` wraps Apache HttpComponents, but doesn't seem to provide a lot of hooks into HC internals, and I've looked into HC itself, but have a hard time navigating the jungle of factories, interfaces and managers.

Comment: It's possible with the transport [properly separated](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write) from the protocol :P

Answer (score 0):

[clj-http](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http) includes the ability to read to and write from an input stream

```
(client/get "http://site.com/bigrequest.html" {:as :stream})

(client/post "http://site.com/resources"
         {:body (clojure.java.io/input-stream "/tmp/foo") :length 1000})
```

you can then wrap this stream in your transport of choice.

Comment: This example reads the response as a stream. Is there a way to have the *request* as a stream?

Answer (score 0):

You can have request body as stream. For that you need to set the `:body` value to any object that implements `InputStream`. Check the function `wrap-input-coercion` at https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/master/src/clj_http/client.clj for more details.

Comment: I need the access to the entire request with the headers (at least).

Comment: I don't think clj-http would be have that option, you would need to use more low level HTTP API for that